# Rules on Migration to Code Review

Tags: discussion, migration, code-review-se

The following Stack Overflow question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968082/modifying-excel-code-to-speed-up-the-process?noredirect=1 was just migrated over to Code Review.  When it was first posted 23ish hours before it was migrated, I read it over and thought it would be a good candidate for migration.

The user is basically asking for a way to clean up their code because it takes to long to run in its current form.  So I flagged and got this:

[image: Flag Declined]

Even though [Code Review SE's Help Page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says:

> If you are looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project in the following areas… Best practices and design pattern usage

A few of the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) users have a [chat going on Code Review chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba) and after discussing the post again this morning, a few additional users flagged for migration, and ***the post was migrated***.

**What does it take for a migration request to be valid and can we ensure all mods are on the same page?**

Comment: should this be a MSO post? this does affect more than just SO.

Comment: @Vogel612 I guess I should have stuck to asking about the specific question and how the Mods handled it  (since apparently people use meta to air their grievances over getting a flag declined or being flag banned - not saying I am flag banned)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alright, this was my fault I handled the flags on this - both times. I'll attempt to explain my reasoning.

I reviewed the question, which appeared to be decent, and your comment pointing out "if the code works, then maybe this would be better on Code Review", but my reasons for declining the flag were:

1. There were already several answers to the question
2. There were no votes to close the question
3. There was no response by the OP to that comment stating that the code worked
4. The fact that you, as the flagger, didn't have significant rep on the target site. We check activity level of the person requesting migration

There were many things that weighed against the migration, so I declined the flag.

We then received 2 more flags to migrate the post by two high rep, highly active users on Code Review. One of the flags specifically stated:

> It seems this question is gathering answers that are much more appropriate for Code Review. Please migrate.

Code Review has very specific guidelines on what is and is not appropriate, including in the answers. During my second look, I decided that the migration was appropriate so I migrated it.

Sorry for the confusion on why your flag was declined but it still wound up migrated.

Comment: guess my activity in the [tag:vba] chat room doesn't count.  But makes sense.

Comment: @Chrismas007 Unfortunately, we don't see that activity. We do check activity on the target sites to make sure that the flagger knows what is and is not on-topic.  Again, sorry for the confusion about this.

Comment: I would like to add (as a moderator on Code Review), that two things should also be reinforced. First, the question has to be off-topic on the source site before migration to the target is OK. Don't migrate things that are on-topic. Why was it not voted-to-close at the same time as the flag? The second thing is that answered questions are harder to migrate because the answers have to keep their value too on Code Review. If there's a +X answer here on SO, it could become a -X answer on Code Review. It is not just about the question.

Comment: @Chrismas007 - no it doesn't count. We're far more interested in your activity on the target site. If you aren't active there then we've no proof you know what you're talking about when you request migration.

Comment: @ChrisF Is it possible that some [tag:vba] users feel that SO is getting to cluttered with bad questions so if we are active on SO, we are looking to be more judicial in the question being on-topic?  Getting it out of the queue of unanswered where I am active might be more important to some than being active at the destination (as long as the destination is valid).

Comment: @Chrismas007 if it's just a bad question then vote/flag to close and/or down-vote. Migration should not be an option for bad questions.

Comment: After re-reading the RubberDuck answer, I suspect your original decision to not migrate was reinforced by the fact that the question was not a review question, and the code did not work. The second time around, the question was for a review, and the code was working. Makes a difference.

Comment: @ChrisF I must admit that I was unaware that I could put two flags on a question.  Although I am working up to 3k to get close vote privs...

Comment: @rolfl: Hm. There's conflicting advice than. Because at least once my request to migrate was rejected, and the reason I later got on meta was along the lines of "no answers yet, no need to involve mods".

Comment: @Deduplicator - migrations are a messy area of Stack Exchange. The theory is they should never be necessary. The reality is that people often cross-post, and they are not necessary. There's never a way to make everyone happy with a migration. Hard/firm rules about migrations will never be satisfactory, and each one should, by any pragmatic measure, be treated on it's own merits. Because of the way migrations to code review work, there's no 'democratic' way to do it. It comes down to a single person's feeling at a specific point in time. This normally works, and worked this time as well.

Answer (score 10):

I guess I'll weigh in on this, because I suspect that I had something to do with it. At the time when the post was originally flagged, I did not feel it was a good fit for Code Review and left a comment saying so. This was because, at the time, the question made it sound as if the user was asking for help implementing a new feature. Also, the code at the time was missing a line of code that was necessary for it to compile. At that point in time, it was not on topic for Code Review.

The post was brought to my attention again this morning. I noticed then that the question had started gathering many answers that were much more along the line of a code review than a "fix the problem" SO answer. One of those answers would not have been an acceptable SO answer at all, as it did not address the performance issue.

That is when I decided to add the line of code that made the code work, re-worded the question so that it would be on topic on either site, and flagged for migration.

At the time you flagged the question for migration, it wasn't on topic for Code Review. It was only after some tweaks to the question that it was. I apologize for any confusion this caused. Please let me know if you have any specific questions about what was changed, or why it was not, and then was, on topic for CR.

Comment: _I suspect that I had something to do with it_ Yes, yes you did. Your flag was detailed about the answers being good CR answers that swayed my decision the second time around.

Comment: Yeah.... that looks an *awful lot* like the message I put in the flag... =;)-

Comment: That would be why giving more details in custom flags are extremely helpful to us.