# More details on when migration of working code to CodeReview.SE is/isn't appropriate

Tags: discussion

I recently received a warning for a rejected flag because I proposed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816442/why-it-is-not-agree-to-clean-code-principles-can-you-point-out) for migration to CodeReview.SE.  The detail given for the denial was "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found **no evidence** to support it."  Like [this user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283752/798371), I was disappointed to get the warning despite a best effort that seems to match the advice and requirements given on meta:

- I used the general flag as described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266750/798371), instead of a comment as noted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260536/798371).
- The post was not
  asking for functionality debugging, as described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269283/798371) as a sign
  of a bad referral.
- The question did not have any of the issues pointed out in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253975/798371) meta question, because it's (at least framed as) the OP's real, working code, and the question does seem to be in the spirit of the paraphrased questions of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260427/798371) meta answer.
- [This meta Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297053/798371) says that flags will be declined if the question is on-topic for SO as well, but the question was "closed as primarily opinion-based" for remaining here.
- At the time I flagged it, the question had no answers.
- The question seemed to meet the checklist criteria for code migration [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254085/798371).

**Is there something I missed?**
Is it even worth learning any of that if one can spend the time to do so and have it not matter anyway?

Comment: We migrate *high quality* questions; we don't throw our garbage into other sites.  That question is *a mess*.

Comment: So if a question is not closed here, it's not good to migrate because it's on topic on both sites.  If it is closed here, then it's not eligible to migrate because it's too low quality, even if the close reason is that it's "primarily opinion-based?"

Comment: You honestly think that that's a high quality question?  It's subjectivity aside, it's still quite awful.  It doesn't even format it's code properly, the spelling/grammar/punctuation is a mess, there's no description of what the code is supposed to do, etc.  You should migrate questions when they're *off topic* on the site that they're on, but would be a *great* question if only they were posted on a site where that topic is in scope.  This is an awful question, even if posted on a site where it's topic is in scope.

Comment: Related: [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Aside from fixable spelling/grammar/punctuation issues (which are not mentioned in the guide and seem tolerated on SE, even in Servy's comment four words earlier), the cited question does seem to meet the description in that guide.

Comment: That question is utter shite.  And it's completely off topic.  The OP has no idea what's wrong with his code, just that something is.  Code Review is for improving working code.  For all we know, OP's code doesn't even work.  Please, no.  Don't suggest migrating anything unless you have over 2k in both locations.  I know you're trying to help, but you're really not.  You need at least 2k to become jaded enough.

Comment: The more I look at that question, the worse it gets.  It's got methods defined outside of a class' scope.  I know Java is a mongrel language, but I'm pretty sure they don't allow for that.  So OP's code splat won't even compile, which means it's definitely off topic for CR.

Comment: @Will OP also knows that it's "clean code principles" at issue, or at least what's being asked about.  If "Don't suggest migrating anything unless you have over 2k in both locations" is a rule in practice, can you **please** make that more obvious in the meta sources linked to, or in the flag dialogue, etc.?  Also, everything's in the scope of `public class Klasa`.

Comment: That's just a rule of thumb.  You have to be around long enough to recognize the help vampires and other suckers of other people's good will.

Comment: @Will If that's the classification, closing questions based on perceptions of the asker as a potential "help vampire" or "sucker of other people's good will," then we should be closing a whole lot more questions on this site.

Comment: Yes, yes we should.  You just don't realize that yet.

Comment: Oh, so you agree with me now?  Awesome.  Glad to help.  And a good day to you, sir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Servy indicates in the comments above, we try to only migrate high-quality questions. I declined your flag because I didn't believe this question was good enough to migrate.

The English alone in that question was pretty rough, and it was a dump of code with a fairly open-ended "what did I do wrong". It didn't seem like something that Code Review would appreciate having on their site, so I saw no reason to migrate it.

Also, it's been suggested by SE staff that we should triage migration requests based on whether the flagger has an established account on the target site. Generally, we've found that only people who have contributed content to an SE site have a good idea as to what's appropriate there. We get so many migration flags every day, and can't possibly know the exact scopes of every site on the network, so when in doubt we'll simply decline migration flags from someone who isn't an active participant on the target site.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is helpful new information, especially the core: "**we'll simply decline migration flags from someone who isn't an active participant on the target site.**" It would be more helpful to put this in the flagging dialogue somewhere so that other folks would know it; that might reduce the number of deemed-unhelpful flags you get and reject.

Comment: @WBT - In order to warn about this, the system would need some context-specific analysis of the flag as you're typing (custom flags can be many things). I've requested such functionality here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309732/provide-context-specific-warnings-at-time-of-flagging-for-incorrect-flag-use , with migration being one of the cases I called out. I agree, it could help.

Comment: "The system would need some context-specific analysis of the flag as you're typing" Not necessarily (though +1 to that meta request). It could just make a statement like "Please note that we generally decline migration requests from users who  have <2k reputation on the site a question is proposed for migration to." That could be included as part of the background string that's already there with some instructions.  Some will read it and think "that's not relevant because my flag's about something else," but that's OK, those folks will just proceed anyway.

Comment: On every custom flag that everyone would cast? There isn't a standard category for general migration requests. Migration requests are only a small fraction of the things people use custom flags for, and having all that text to go through every time they wanted to flag would only lead to it being ignored. Having this be targeted to the situation at hand would be the best way to get them to pay attention to these warnings.